# Paramiko exec_command with multiple commands on Cisco router not providing any output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cisco

```
login_user = 'xyz'
login_pass = 'xyz'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False, timeout=5)
print "success loggedin"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("term len 0 ; show int desc | i Tu ; show ip interface brief | in Tunnel ; show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf AWS summary | i 169.25 ; show ip route vrf AWS bgp")
all_output = stdout.read()
print all_output
```

Above is my code snippet, passing just one command prints the results just fine, however with multiple commands as above, it does not work (no output). The device being logged onto is a Cisco ASR1006 - Does it have anything to do with the device?

Any help is much appreciated!

---

Since multiple commands didn't work, I'm using below code with multiple exec_command, but this this takes about 30-40 secs each execution..
ssh.connect needed for each command execution?

```
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show int desc | i Tu')
vpc_ints = stdout.read()
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip interface brief | in Tunnel')
vpc_peers = stdout.read()
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf AWS summary | i 169.25')
vpc_bgp_routes = stdout.read()
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip route vrf AWS bgp')
ip_routes_list = stdout.read()
```

---

As suggested in comments, I have also tried to call `exec_command` multiple times over one connection:

```
ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show int desc | i Tu')
vpc_ints = stdout.read()
#ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip interface brief | in Tunnel')
vpc_peers = stdout.read()
#ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf AWS summary | i 169.25')
vpc_bgp_routes = stdout.read()
#ssh.connect(device, username=login_user, password=login_pass, look_for_keys=False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip route vrf AWS bgp')
ip_routes_list = stdout.read()
ssh.close()
```

But that's failing with:

```
File "C:\Python27\myvpndashboard\myvpnapp\tunnel_summary.py", line 179, in dataset_build
cisco_show(device)
File "C:\Python27\myvpndashboard\myvpnapp\tunnel_summary.py", line 36, in cisco_show
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show ip interface brief | in Tunnel')
File "C:\Users\sduraisami\Envs\myvpndashboard\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 472, in exec_command
chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\sduraisami\Envs\myvpndashboard\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 765, in open_session
timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\sduraisami\Envs\myvpndashboard\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 889, in open_channel
raise e
EOFError
```

Answer (score 0):

(At least some) Cisco routers are known not to support multiple commands in one "exec" request:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m

> **With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even** put multiple lines in this file and **execute more than one command in sequence**, or a whole shell script; **but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers**. In particular, **it is known not to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers**.

---

Normally, you could run `exec_command` multiple times over the same connection. But that does not seem possible with Cisco either.

Then I'd recommends you to stick with reopening the session for each command. While inefficient, its a reliable approach.

---

If the inefficiency is not acceptable, you can use a shell channel like:

```
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
channel.send('command 1\n')
channel.send('command 2\n')
channel.send('command 3\n')
while not channel.recv_ready():
    time.sleep(3)
out = channel.recv(9999)
print out
```

But that's not reliable. It is difficult tell when an output of one command finishes and the other starts. It is also difficult tell, if you got all output already or not. And as Paramiko always uses PTY, you get a lot of unwanted output, like prompts, command echoes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was able to work around the problem. Instead of using the exec_command() function, I opened a shell session and then used the send() function with the shell object I created.

```
from time import sleep
import paramiko

username = "username" 
password = "password"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


ssh.connect(
    ip_address, 
    port=22, 
    username=username, 
    password=password, 
    look_for_keys=False, 
    banner_timeout=200
)
connection = ssh.invoke_shell()


connection.send("show int desc | i Tu")
output = connection.recv(65535)
print(output.decode("UTF-8"))
sleep(.5)
connection.send("\n")


connection.send("show ip interface brief | i Tunnel")
output = connection.recv(65535)
print(output.decode("UTF-8"))
sleep(.5)
connection.send("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin said, "exec_command" is not the way to go for this.
You can use "chan.send()"

To determine whether ready to receive the next command, you can do something like (after creating your list of commands, of course):

```
buff = ""
while "#" not in buff:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        response = channel.recv(4086).decode("utf-8")
        buff += resp
# then do whatever you want with this output
```

Martin was correct in his response, so I've been playing around with it and this works perfectly for my needs. When using a CISCO device, you'll typically see "#" in your prompt line, and so you can constantly check to see if this prompt line is present (your mileage may vary, so you can include more of the prompt line than just "#"). Once it's there, you'll break out of the while loop.

Comment: The `recv_ready` is not an indication that shell channel is ready for the next command. There's no such indication. The "shell" is a black box with an input and an output.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have edited my post to make it a bit more suitable. This is an example that I used yesterday, right before posting it. It does indeed make an assumption about output you will find at the end of the data you want to be able to parse later, but it's a way that can easily be thrown into a function and called upon whenever needed.